# Equivalent to cherry pick for removing commit

Tags: git

I want to remove a commit from the history, a single merge commit and nothing also, before or after.
Is there some git command to do so? Similar to cherry-pick but instead aiming to remove a commit from a branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you try to achieve with this, there are different alternatives.

What you describe could be interpreted as *reverting* a commit (see [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)). It creates a new commit on top of the current tree tip, containing the exact reverse changes that a given commit introduced. (It does not rewrite history.)

```
git revert <commitHash>
```

Your commit will *not* be removed from history, it won't be modified in any way. But the changes it brought will be cancelled by the new commit you added.

Answer (score 1):

```
git revert
```

Can be used to remove commits. Add your SHA after the command to specify which commit to revert.